# How do I apply potion effects to a player wearing armor with a special name with command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making special classes for my server, and I want to give someone underwater breathing whenever they are wearing a helmet named *scuba*. How do I do this with command blocks?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is */testfor* a player with a helmet with a custom name *scuba*.  Test for the slot number they have it in, (helmets are 103)  This command should do all that:

```
/testfor @p[r=2] {Inventory:[{Slot:103b,tag:{display:{Name:"scuba"}}}]}
```

Hook it up to a clock of your choice and if the /testfor command reads true then have a comparator ready to activate a sticky piston that pushes a redstone block to activate the command

```
/effect @p minecraft:water_breathing
```

When they leave your set radius or remove there helmet the sticky piston will deactivate pulling the redstone block activating the command

```
/effect @p clear
```

[image]
This is a list of the inventory slot numbers.

[image]

The Youtuber Dragnoz also has a great video on how to do things like this.